# JUnit: Can I keep the common parts of the spring context?

Tags: java, spring, junit

I have some unit tests with Spring. All the tests load a spring configuration file, and then add some more.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:beans.xml" }, inheritLocations = true)
public abstract class TestBase {
}

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:extraBeansOne.xml" }, inheritLocations = true)
public class TestOne extends TestBase {

  @Test
  public void testA() {
  }
}

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:extraBeansTwo.xml" }, inheritLocations = true)
public class TestTwo extends TestBase {

  @Test
  public void testB() {
  }
}
```

There's also a suite with the two tests:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({ TestOne.class, TestTwo.class })
public class TestSuite {
}
```

In the common spring configuration file, I have a bean:

```
<beans ...>
  <bean id="testBean" class="com.example.TestBean" />
<bean>
```

The problem is that, when I run the suite, the *testBean* gets loaded twice, once for each test class. Since it is defined in a common configuration file, is there any way to prevent it from loading multiple times?

Comment: Where are you actually using 'testBean' in your tests?

Comment: What do you mean "gets loaded twice"? Spring beans are singletons by default, so if you have two instances of your testBean, it means that you somehow have more than one Spring context.

Comment: @isah, it does not matter whether I am using the bean or not, it gets loaded along with the context.

Comment: @Olaf, yes, one context gets loaded when the first test runs, and another one when the second test runs; they both get unloaded at the end of the suite, so during the second test I have two 'testBean's - one from each context. The question is, can I somehow reuse the common part of the context, so I only have one 'testBean'?

Comment: @Cosmin: As Ralph answered, there is not much you can do with your current approach. In my unit test I load context on the class setup and, if I need test-specific beans, inject them manually in the Java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is not really a chance to reuse them.

The Spring Junit Runner reuses the spring contexts over different tests, but only if there files are the same.

> [9.3.2.1 Context management and caching](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testing-ctx-management)
>   ...
>
> Test classes provide an array containing the resource locations of XML configuration metadata - typically in the classpath - that is used to configure the application. These locations are the same as or similar to the list of configuration locations specified in web.xml or other deployment configuration files.

If this is very important for you and you are willing to spend time on it, then you can try to implement something that bases on the fact that application context can have a parent (like the two contexts in web applications, one defined for `ContextLoaderListener` the other defined for `DispatcherServlet`)) Then it is may possible to use/reuse the parent context in different test method dependend child contexts.

@See [Spring Reference: Chapter 9.3.5.2 Context management and caching](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management)